# How to share a folder for domain users only

Tags: vb.net, shared-directory

I have been tasked with sharing a folder on my local pc to my network but only to the same Domain User.

This is my code so far but I cannot see where I can add Shared Permissions to?

```
Public Class URNScanning
Private Const URN_SCANNED = "URN_Scanned"
Private Const URN_SCANNED_NAME = "URN_Scanned"
Private Const URN_SCANNED_DESCRIPTION = "URN_Scanned_Files"

Public Shared Sub ShareFolder()
    Dim sharedPath As String = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, URN_SCANNED)
    If Not (Directory.Exists(sharedPath)) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(sharedPath)
    End If

    Dim managementClass As New ManagementClass("Win32_Share")
    Dim inParams As ManagementBaseObject = managementClass.GetMethodParameters("Create")
    inParams.Item("Description") = URN_SCANNED_DESCRIPTION
    inParams.Item("Name") = URN_SCANNED_NAME
    inParams.Item("Path") = sharedPath
    inParams.Item("Type") = 0
    If (DirectCast(managementClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, Nothing).Properties.Item("ReturnValue").Value, UInt32) <> 0) Then
        Throw New Exception("Unable to share directory.")
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the WMI API, so I can't tell for sure, but maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15965101) could have some pointers for you?

Comment: @Mark nor am I :)  thanks for link.  I shall see if it helps